# Cover full height of notification using custom layout in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am trying to create custom notification in my android application. 
I am using following code

Custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_notification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_background"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I am creating my notification

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(activity.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

            Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)

                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .build();
            noti.contentView = contentView;
            // Hide the notification after its selected
            noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

            notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

The notification is created, however it does not cover the full height on the notification bar even though I am using fill_parent for height attribute.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: You wanna fill the complete Notification Bar with one Notification?

Comment: No, only the notification which I created should cover the height for the notification. Currently it is filling only half of the notification

Answer (score 1):

it's too late but helped me, wish it could help you too.
make a background image in xml or png which is transparent (if you want you can color it), and the height of background image must be longer than the notification height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_notification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tran"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_background"
        android:clickable="true" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

tran.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <size android:width="400dp" android:height="400dp"/>
</shape>
```